# android how to put heading for an BaseAdpater

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I wanna to put heading for an BaseAdapter.
like[image] attached screenshot

This is an android app Pulse news reader. I want to know how they made this front page. How they put headings for every image adapter. What the concept they used here.
Plz anybody tell me with sample example.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to think about, the data and the layouts.

The list that's being displayed is an array of items where each item represents a feed.  The feed represents an array of articles.

Think of the objects something like this

Feed

- Title (`String`)
- Articles (`List<Article>`)

Article

- Thumbnail (`Image`)
- Headline (`String`)

Your adapter is going to be bound to a `List<Feed>`, and the layout file that you use to display a "Feed" item is going to have a vertical LinearLayout that displays the title and then below that a horizontal LinearLayout containing the Articles array (using layout_weight to make each item hold an equal amount of horizontal space)

Comment: multiple adapter shoud be used there or what?  Just see the heading it is attached to that image scroller. If i take Linearlayout is it coming like this?

Comment: Is all should be define in one xml file?

Comment: Can you scroll each Feed item to the right?  If so, that's an adapter/listview combination as well.  There are a lot of ways to do this, the only way to really understand what the up and down sides are to all the different approaches are is to start whipping up some code and see.  As far as the xml files, I would use multiple.  I would make a feed_item.xml and an article_item.xml.  The feed_item.xml would be as I described above, and I'd get a reference to the horiz LinearLayout that holds the articles and fill it with instances of article_item.xml, etc.

Comment: Would u give me some sample example for better understanding?